# Thailand customs and round-trip to Hong Kong

Tags: thailand, local-customs, shopping, hong-kong, southeast-asia

I'm going to travel to Thailand for about a month. Inbound and outbound flights are through BKK.

What I want to do is a round-trip to Hong Kong for a shopping before leave Thailand. In particular I'd like to buy MacBook and iPhone, since they're much cheaper in HK than in my country.

What concerns me here is Thai customs. As I can see [on their site](http://www.customs.go.th/wps/wcm/connect/custen/travellers/arriving+in+thailand/arrivinginthailand) "If you are bringing in with you the items with total combined value more than 10,000 baht, these items are subject to import taxes and duties." 10000 THB is about 285 USD at the moment.

Does it applicable if I'm going to leave Thailand on the same day or in couple of days? Does it matter if items are unboxed?

Another related question is shall I pay duties if I bring my MacBook, iPhone and iPad into Thailand on my first entry? Their total value is probably above stated limit.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Prices must be high for you, if the cost of airfare to HK, plus hotels while you there, is less than the price difference.  Make sure anything you buy comes with a global warranty not a regional one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the items are for your personal use, especially if they are unboxed, and you will be departing the country with them, then it is very unlikely that you would attract any attention.  The restrictions typically relate to goods and gifts that would be left in the Kingdom.

I am a software developer based in HK and I travel 20+ times a year through BKK.  I always have a laptop (often 2), and half a dozen mobiles phones and tablets in my bag, and I have never experienced any problems.

One trick you can try if you want to retain the packaging, is to mail the boxes and receipts back to Ukraine. As well as being the cheapest place in the world for Apple products, Hong Kong has an extremely cheap and efficient postal service.  A 1kg package by land to Ukraine would be just HKD $53.

Comment: Wow, that's a neat trick to retain packages!

Comment: Also, if you're looking to get the best possible price, then the computer centres in Wan Chai, Mong Kok or Sham Shui Po will often give up to 5% discount for payment in cash.

Comment: That's interesting! Even though I prefer to not carry a lot of cash especially in foreign country, it worth to consider.